# Best way to parse line with 2 mailing addresses separated by whitespace with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing PDF files and have 2 addresses left aligned. In addition to the line below the city,state and zip are separated as well.

The address to the right always starts at an index > 150 (from start of line). I can trigger a match of any text from an index > 150 and stop at the \n newline but this method seems memory intensive and slow. I have about 200 lines of text in the pdf. I also know that the adress lines (7 total) always occur between line 40 ad 48. Looking for some simple alternatives to parse this data.

```
1011 VALLEY BELT RD                4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD\n


open (FILE, "pdftotext -layout file.pdf - |");
while(<FILE>) {
  $i++;
  my($line) = $_;
  $line=~s/\n$/ | [NL]/; # just to visualize the newline on screen
  print "\n<div class=\"line\"><div>$i</div>$line</div>";
  }
close FILE;
```

The pdf's are generated by an application so they are controlled

Comment: Could you please show use the code you are already using to parse the files? We can then suggest improvements. Also, I am amazed that you can extract the addresses with such precise formatting; it is my unfortunate experience that pdf extraction messes everything up. For 200 lines of data, I'd rather not think about performance. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that you are dealing with fixed width data, you can use `unpack` to extract the fields:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# creating your input string
my $str = sprintf "%-150s%s\n", "1011 VALLEY BELT RD",
                                "4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD";

# unpack 150 ascii chars, space padded (A150) and same to end of string (A*)
my ($first, $second) = unpack "A150A*", $str;

print Dumper $first, $second;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = '1011 VALLEY BELT RD';
$VAR2 = '4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD';
```

If you know the line numbers this data will be in, you can use the line number variable [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) to find the right place. For example:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    next unless $. >= 40;
    # do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I am dealing with fixed position of data. I do not know the data util the line is read.

Comment: @chrisrth Well, that's quite a different statement from the one in your question, where you said you knew the address to the right always started at position > 150.

Comment: position > 150 is true. I was a little confused by your example. my ($first, $second) = unpack "A150A*", $str; I'll have to load dumper and test. in this statement is $str the $line in my example? In the line before you are "creating input string" with the addresses pre-loaded. I don't know the addresses at this point.

Comment: @chrisrth I am not sure what you are talking about. Of course you don't know the addresses beforehand, then you wouldn't need to extract them, now would you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use match with regrex to get the items from the line.  Using groupings, you can make matches and then save the addresses.

With the sample of the data provided, here is what I came up with:

```
while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  m/(\d+\s+.*)\s+(\d+\s+.*)/;
  print "$1\n";
  print "$2\n";
}

__DATA__
1011 VALLEY BELT RD                4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD
```

$1 will contain the first address and $2 will contain the second address.

This does assume there is a space between the addresses and the address will start with at least one digit.

Comment: There is always multiple spaces between string 1 and string 2 but I cannot assume string 2 starts with a number or that there will not be more than 1 whitespace between characters in string 1 or 2. I can assume there will be more than 5 spaces between string A and string B.

Answer (score -1):

Complete solution based on Dumper by @TLP

** Address

```
1011 VALLEY BELT RD                4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD\n
Philadelphia, PA                   Kansas City, MO\n
18659                              69869\n
```

** Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $i=0;
my $lAddr;
my $rAddr;
open (FILE, "pdftotext -layout file.pdf - |");
while(<FILE>) {
  $i++;
  my($line) = $_;
  if ($i>40 && $i<=48) {
    # unpack 150 ascii chars, space padded (A150) and same to end of string (A*)
    my ($VAR1, $VAR2) = unpack "A150A*", $line;
    $lAddr.=$VAR1;
    $rAddr.=$VAR2;
    }
  }
close FILE;
```

**Output:**

```
$lAddr = '1011 VALLEY BELT RD Philadelphia, PA 18659';
$rAddr = '4569 EAST TWINSBURG ROAD Kansas City, MO 69869';
```